# trying to watermarking an image with MagickWand method using python

Tags: python, c, imagemagick, ctypes, watermark

I have a problem integrating Python and C through ctypes .

The problem is in the method MagicSteganoImage , this method returns 0 therefore can not write the final result.

Someone help me? thanks to all.

```
path="path/photo.png"
markpath="path/mark.png"
libwand=CDLL("libMagickWand-6.Q16.so.2")
libwand.MagickWandGenesis()
mw=libwand.NewMagickWand()
libwand.MagickReadImage(mw,path)
mark=libwand.NewMagickWand()
libwand.MagickReadImage(mark,markpath)
result=libwand.NewMagickWand()
result = libwand.MagickSteganoImage(mw,mark,0)
libwand.MagickWriteImage(result,dest)
```

Answer (score 2):

You *must* tell python how to interact with C API.

```py
from ctypes import *
libwand=CDLL("libMagickWand-6.Q16.so.2")
# Communicated how python should handle ctypes
libwand.NewMagickWand.restype = c_void_p
libwand.MagickReadImage.argtypes = (c_void_p, c_char_p)
libwand.MagickSteganoImage.argtypes = (c_void_p, c_void_p, c_int)
libwand.MagickSteganoImage.restype = c_void_p
libwand.MagickWriteImage.argtypes = (c_void_p, c_char_p)
# ... work
```

As well as build out error handling to interact with C-API exceptions.

For additional help, you can evaluate the [source code](https://github.com/dahlia/wand/blob/master/wand/api.py) of [wand](/questions/tagged/wand).